DeltaLake/DeltaTable merge operation inserts/duplicates matched rows not updating them
The following URLs are for two DeltaTables ake_original and ake_updates:

ake_original
ake_updates

Each DeltaTable has two columns:
AKE_ID PRIMARY KEY pa.String()
MODIFIED_DATE pa.timestamp('us')


Details:
First DeltaTable 'ake_original' has 59,767 rows. for all the data inserted on 07 June 2024 from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.
Second DeltaTable 'ake_updates' has 6,262 rows. representing some of the data inserted on 07 June 2024 from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 but updated on 08 June 2024 from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59.


Using below Python code to merge updated rows into the original rows using unique column AKE_ID resulting in rows duplication.


It inserts/duplicates 4,276 and updates 1,986 rows.

What is the reason for data duplication ?

from deltalake import DeltaTable, write_deltalake
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

deltaTable = DeltaTable('ake_original')
dataset_update = ds.dataset('ake_updates')
df = dataset_update.to_table()

(
    deltaTable.merge(
        source=df,
        predicate="s.AKE_ID = t.AKE_ID", 
        source_alias="s",
        target_alias="t",
    )
    .when_matched_update_all()
    .when_not_matched_insert_all()
    .execute()
)

print(deltaTable.history())


if you have two Delta tables, why do you use pyarrow, dataset and pandas?

also, are you 100% certain that 4276 are really duplicates?

@AlexanderPavlov I’m certain 100% that 4,276 are really duplicates, I have another script check the same IDs in both delta tables and all the 6,262 rows are exist in the original 59,767 rows dataset.

@AlexanderPavlov I have modified the code to use dataset only

why not DeltaTable('ake_updates').toDF()?

I took a look at _delta_log of original database. You were not doing inserts. You were doing overwrites so original database is not 59767 records long, but just 9767.
For example, changes made by 0th and by 1st revisions
...0000.json
{"add":{"path":"0-0869ed37-2f6c-4987-a403-f9735a6d1eba-0.parquet", ....

...0001.json

{"add":{"path":"1-b46332c9-3183-40d9-a78c-89dbffbd430e-0.parquet"...
{"remove":{"path":"0-0869ed37-2f6c-4987-a403-f9735a6d1eba-0.parquet",....{"mode":"Overwrite","partitionBy":"[]"...

1st revision removes file created by 0th revision and adds new one but it is just 10000 records
You can check the rest - you remove previous file and create new one.
Solution: when you are populating original database, you should use mode=append

To recover overwritten records (never done by myself but you can try):

delete original/_delta_log folder
use parquet-to-delta conversion to create new Delta table from existing parquet files.


You are right I mistakenly used “overwrite” mode, and because it’s totally typo issue, I wasn’t believe I did this mistake even while I was reading this reply but I went back to the ETL tool and found it’s written using “overwrite” mode. This the importance of second eye, much appreciated.

The weird thing it took 12 seconds to merge these 6,262 rows which for me a lot of time.

Simple print(deltaTable.toDF().count()) would give you a clue
